# Add block before content in magento page

Tags: php, layout, template, blocks, xml

I need to add a block right after the breadcrumbs in one of my pages, `my-page`

I tried creating a block called `my-block` in the admin, and adding `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my-block') ?>` in `frontend/theme/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml` and it doesn't show the contents of the block `my-block`.

I also added

```
<page-name>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="my-block" as="my-block" before="content" after="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/my-block.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</page-name>
```

In the local.xml file, but I'm not sure if it was really necessary.

Am I missing something?

thanks

Comment: Where did you add that layout xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `my-page` is a cms page and you want to show your custom block only in this cms page, then this is what you need to include a custom block just below the breadcrumb block.

### 1. Define your custom block

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\layout\local.xml`

```
<cms_page_view> <!-- layout update handle -->
    <reference name="root"> <!-- parent block of our custom block -->
        <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.top.block" as="my_custom_top_block" template="custom/template.phtml" /> <!-- definition of custom block -->
    </reference>
</cms_page_view>
```

This code snippet defines our  block and include it in `root` block in the case of a cms page rendition. This means this block will be available when a cms page is rendered in frontend. You need to include the block inside `root` block because it is the block which holds all structural blocks and `breadcrumb` block is a structural block. Obviously your block is also a structural block.

### 2. Specify Where should Custom Block Appear

This is the next important step. Defining a block will not render your block automatically. You need to specify where should it appear. For that you need to open the `root template` and add the below code there

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template/page/[root-template].phtml`

```
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_custom_top_block') ?>
    <div class="col-main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `[root-template].phtml` would be the active root template in your theme. Eg : `1column.phtml`, `2columns-left.phtml` etc. It would be good if you add the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_custom_top_block') ?>` just below `breadcrumb` call in every root templates as I shown above (root templates are phtml files which are avaialable in `template/page` folder).

### 3. Define your custom block template

This is the last step. Go ahead and create a custom block template which we have specified in our layout udpate.

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template/custom/template.phtml`

```
<div> UREKKAAAA </div>
```

Now clear the cache and load the page again. You will see `UREKKAAAA` just below breadcrumb.

Comment: @Gazta : sorry I didnt get you.

Answer (score 1):

Widget, or Layout update

for Layout can try like this code

```
<reference name="top.container">
    <block type="core/template"
                   name="linkcoupon_block"
                   as="linkcoupon_block"
                   template="linkcoupon/static.phtml"
                   output="toHtml"
            />
</reference>
```